# Add an external input value to form on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a typical form:

```
<form action="" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post">
    <textarea name="content"></textarea>
</form>
```

and an not-inside-a-form element:

```
<input type="password" name="password">
```

How do I add the value of password into the form when I submit the form?

```
$('form').submit(function(){
   //hmmm
});
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Create a hidden field in the form and copy the password field value to that field on submit.
Like this.

```
<form action="" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post">
    <textarea name="content"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="password" id="ps">
</form>

<input type="password" name="password" id="ps1">
```

And in on submit function.

```
$('form').submit(function(){
   $('input#ps').val($('input#ps1').val());
   return true;
});
```

Comment: Ah, why didn't I think of that. Thanks!

Comment: is there add way to more more fields to it?

Comment: @coder771 yes you can add any no of fields before return.

Comment: @coder771 You can just add many hidden input fields as you like

Answer (score 6):

The not-yet-supported-but-HTML5-compliant way to do this "correctly" is to give your `<input>` element a [`[form]` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#attr-fae-form):

```
<form id="foo">
    ...stuff...
</form>

<input type="password" id="bar" form="foo" />
```

Eventually you may be able to use this as a solution, but until more browsers support the `[form]` attribute, you'll have to polyfill it with JavaScript.

Comment: technically none of the browser support it yet?

Comment: @Severus, I believe some browsers support it, but I haven't checked, and I can't find any compatibility tables. It's not even listed on [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=forms) yet, so I assume that browser support is sketchy at best. Fortunately, this sort of interaction is pretty easy to polyfill with JS.

Comment: is there add way to more more fields to it

Comment: @coder771, I'm not sure I understand what you're asking, and I would encourage you to use the "ask a question" button at the top of the page when you do have a fully formed question to ask.

Comment: here in question there was a requirement to send password field, i have 2 field to send in submit

Comment: @coder771, ...so add the `[form]` attribute to the other field as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('form').submit(function(){
   var password = $('input[type="password"]');
   password.appendTo($(this));
   //or $(this).append(password);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

include a hidden input element inside of the form,
on the outer input's change event, assign the inner input the outer inputs value.

```
<form action="" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post">
    <textarea name="content"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" id="inner" />
</form>
<input type="password" name="password" >


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#outer').change(function(){
            $('#inner').val($(this).val());
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use hidden input field inside form like this:

ex :   `<input type="hidden" name="pass">`

When you submit the form like this :

```
$('form').submit(function(){
 <!-- Save the value of password into the hidden field
  Note : Password here should just be one field in that page -->
 $('input[name="pass"]').val($('input[type="password"]').val());
 return true;
```

});